# sql query-Joining 2 tables with a condition of a column but their values are null

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

If `Table A` and `Table B` has a column each named `ViewType` and all their values are `NULL`.
When we try to join the 2 tables on condition `A.ViewType =B.ViewType` ,what result should we expect?
All the rows as answer or 0 rows affected as answer?

Comment: You would expect no rows.  Almost any comparison with `NULL` returns "unknown" which is treated as false in comparisons.

Comment: I don't understand the goal of such kind of query. If `A.ViewType` is `NULL` i wouldn't expect this row in the result of an `INNER JOIN`. So if every ViewType of Table A are `NULL`, i expect no rows as result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will be 0 rows affected.

**- Script Start**

SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ViewType = B.ViewType

**Script End**

Answer (score 0):

Please use condition in where clause:

```
WHERE ISNULL(a.viewtype,1) = ISNULL(b.viewtype,1);
```